# getting error-could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dll, asp.net-web-api

Accidently I had deleted a reference of System.Web.Mvc of version "5.0.0.0" in my web api project,now when I tried to build it,it successfully builds and adds a dll of of System.Web.Mvc of version "4.0.0.0".Now when I run it I got error

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

In my web config following lines are written

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
```

When i remove the auto added dll of 'System.Web.Mvc' and adds a dll of 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0' from my nuget packages 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.0.0' error disappears.

My question is from **which location i should add my deleted dll or how to restore my accidently deleted dll?**

Comment: try uninstall and then install Microsoft ASP.NET MVC with nuget

Comment: The location where Nuget package is downloaded is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is from which location i should add my deleted dll or how
>   to restore my accidently deleted dll?

There are two action here:

1. If you deleted the dll itself
2. If you have deleted a reference to the dll

To handle first case, you will have to restore the Nuget package, that's it. For more information on package restore, check this [link](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-restore)

To handle second case which you mentioned in your question in very first line, just add a reference to the dll. The dll location is same as where you Nuget package is downloaded.

Hope this helps.